# Hierarchical query using oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c, hierarchical-data

We have following table to query data from,

### EMPLOYEE_ABSENCE_TAB

| emp_id | absence_id | from_date | to_date | absence_continuation |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 1 | 01/01/2022 | 03/01/2022 |  |
| 100 | 2 | 01/02/2022 | 05/02/2022 | 1 |
| 200 | 3 | 01/01/2022 | 07/01/2022 |  |
| 200 | 4 | 10/01/2022 | 14/01/2022 | 3 |
| 200 | 5 | 16/01/2022 | 20/01/2022 | 4 |
| 300 | 6 | 01/01/2022 | 14/01/2022 |  |

We need to connect data hierarchically based on the following logic.
Output should be emp_id, absence_days, from_date and to_date.

- absence_days : number of absence days = sum(to_date - from_date)
- from_date : first from_date where absence_continuation is NULL
- to_date : last to_date connect by prior absence_id = absence_continuation

---

### Expected Outcome

| emp_id | absence_days | from_date | to_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 8 | 01/01/2022 | 05/02/2022 |
| 200 | 17 | 01/01/2022 | 20/01/2022 |
| 300 | 14 | 01/01/2022 | 14/01/2022 |

I tried hierarchical but could able to come up with working solution. How can this be achieved using hierarchical query in Oracle SQL?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to consider the hierarchy in the data (assuming that there are no overlaps); you just need to aggregate:

```sql
SELECT emp_id,
       SUM(to_date - from_date + 1) AS absence_days,
       MIN(from_date) AS from_date,
       MAX(to_date) AS to_date
FROM   EMPLOYEE_ABSENCE_TAB
GROUP BY emp_id
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE_ABSENCE_TAB
(emp_id, absence_id, from_date, to_date, absence_continuation) AS
SELECT 100, 1, DATE '2022-01-01', DATE '2022-01-03', NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 100, 2, DATE '2022-02-01', DATE '2022-02-05', 1    FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 200, 3, DATE '2022-01-01', DATE '2022-01-07', NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 200, 4, DATE '2022-01-10', DATE '2022-01-14', 3    FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 200, 5, DATE '2022-01-16', DATE '2022-01-20', 4    FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 300, 6, DATE '2022-01-01', DATE '2022-01-14', NULL FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | EMP_ID | ABSENCE_DAYS | FROM_DATE | TO_DATE |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 100 | 8 | 2022-01-01 00:00:00 | 2022-02-05 00:00:00 |
> | 200 | 17 | 2022-01-01 00:00:00 | 2022-01-20 00:00:00 |
> | 300 | 14 | 2022-01-01 00:00:00 | 2022-01-14 00:00:00 |

---

If you did want to consider the hierarchy and get the duration of each absence (and not the total absences per employee) then you can use:

```sql
SELECT emp_id,
       absence_id,
       SUM(to_date - from_date + 1) AS absence_days,
       MIN(from_date) AS from_date,
       MAX(to_date) AS to_date
FROM   (
  SELECT emp_id,
         CONNECT_BY_ROOT absence_id AS absence_id,
         to_date - from_date + 1 AS absence_days,
         from_date,
         to_date
  FROM   EMPLOYEE_ABSENCE_TAB
  START WITH absence_continuation IS NULL
  CONNECT BY PRIOR absence_id = absence_continuation
)
GROUP BY
       emp_id,
       absence_id
```

Which outputs the same (with an additional `absence_id` column for the `id` of the first part of the absence) for your sample data as you only have a single absence for each employee; if you had more absences then it would aggregate each absence separately.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=aebce1d0c4e7c43e58582903e5dc1a2c)*